# Memory monitoring: C++ code to print the PSS (Proportional Set Size) of accessable processes in linux

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, embedded-linux

Memory monitoring: Could anyone post a C++ code to print the PSS (Proportional Set Size) of accessable processes in Linux.
Given the python code to perform the same:

import os, sys, re, pwd

```
'''
Print the user name, pid, pss, and the command line for all accessable
processes in pss descending order.
'''
# Get the user name, pid, pss, and the command line information for all
# processes that are accessable. Ignore processes where the permission is
# denied.
ls = []   # [(user, pid, pss, cmd)]
for pid in filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), os.listdir('/proc')):
    try:
        ls.append((owner_of_process(pid), pid, pss_of_process(pid), cmdline_of_process(pid)))
    except IOError:
        pass

# Calculate the max length of the user name, pid, and pss in order to
# print them in aligned columns.
userlen = 0
pidlen = 0
psslen = 0
for (user, pid, pss, cmd) in ls:
    userlen = max(userlen, len(user))
    pidlen = max(pidlen, len(pid))
    psslen = max(psslen, len(str(pss)))

# Get the width of the terminal.
with os.popen('tput cols') as fp:
    term_width = int(fp.read().strip())

# Print the information. Ignore kernel modules since they allocate memory
# from the kernel land, not the user land, and PSS is the memory
# consumption of processes in user land.
fmt = '%%-%ds  %%%ds  %%%ds  %%s' % (userlen, pidlen, psslen)
print(fmt % ('USER', 'PID', 'PSS', 'COMMAND'))
for (user, pid, pss, cmd) in sorted(ls, lambda x, y: cmp(y[2], x[2])):
    if cmd != '':
        print((fmt % (user, pid, pss, cmd))[:term_width - 1])
```

def pss_of_process(pid):
    '''
    Return the PSS of the process specified by pid in KiB (1024 bytes unit)

```
@param pid  process ID
@return     PSS value
'''
with file('/proc/%s/smaps' % pid) as fp:
    return sum([int(x) for x in re.findall('^Pss:\s+(\d+)', fp.read(), re.M)])
```

def cmdline_of_process(pid):
    '''
    Return the command line of the process specified by pid.

```
@param pid  process ID
@return     command line
'''
with file('/proc/%s/cmdline' % pid) as fp:
    return fp.read().replace('\0', ' ').strip()
```

def owner_of_process(pid):
    '''
    Return the owner of the process specified by pid.

```
@param pid  process ID
@return     owner
'''
return pwd.getpwuid(os.stat('/proc/%s' % pid).st_uid).pw_name
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    pss_main()

Comment: No one will convert your Phyton script here into C++. What we could do is to help you when you get some errors in your c++ code.

Comment: Try to convert it yourself, then when you are mostly done, come back and ask for help to take of the edges

Comment: Require file operations to do the following in C++:with file('/proc/%s/smaps' % pid) as fp:
    return sum([int(x) for x in re.findall('^Pss:\s+(\d+)', fp.read(), re.M)]) Please help

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and fix the code formatting. I would've done but I was uncertain about indentation starting after `import` until first `def`. (I'm rather a novice concerning Python...)

Comment: The code is in correct format , please consider it as a single code including all the three functions.